# using lxml capture element value then remove to create a template xml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

I am looking for an elegant way to open a series of XMLs in a folder, to capture all element values into a dictionary, then in the remove the element values for elements only within the parent 'body' element, and save as a template file

Here's an example of the different XML files I am using, in these examples I am looking to remove the values:

```
spinach,cabbage and broccoli:
```

xml File1

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootelement>
    <Header>
        <Somebranch>
            <Somebranchitem1>HeaderValue1</Somebranchitem1>
            <Somebranchitem2>HeaderValue2</Somebranchitem2>
        </Somebranch>
        <anitem>1</anitem>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <BodyItem>
            <subbodyitem>spinach</subbodyitem>
        </BodyItem>
    </Body>
</rootelement>
```

xml File2

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootelement>
    <Header>
        <Somebranch>
            <Somebranchitem1>HeaderValue1</Somebranchitem1>
            <Somebranchitem2>HeaderValue2</Somebranchitem2>
        </Somebranch>
        <anitem>123e</anitem>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <AnItem>
            <Adifferentnameditem>cabbage</Adifferentnameditem>
            <Adifferentnameditem2>broccoli</Adifferentnameditem2>
        </AnItem>
    </Body>
</rootelement>
```

After extraction I am looking to create a new file as a template a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rootelement>
    <Header>
        <Somebranch>
            <Somebranchitem1>HeaderValue1</Somebranchitem1>
            <Somebranchitem2>HeaderValue2</Somebranchitem2>
        </Somebranch>
        <anitem>123e</anitem>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <AnItem>
            <Adifferentnameditem></Adifferentnameditem>
            <Adifferentnameditem2></Adifferentnameditem2>
        </AnItem>
    </Body>
</rootelement>
```

I can extract the values into a dictionary, but because the 'Body' sub elements have differing names depending on the XML file I am having problems creating a generic loop.

Here's my function code so far:

```
import lxml.etree as et

def process_xml(xmlfilename):
    doc = et.parse(xmlfilename)

    params_dict = {}
    for tag in doc.iter():
        if not len(tag):
            element_name = tag.tag
            element_value = tag.text
            #print(tag.tag, ' >>>>>> ', tag.text)
            params_dict[element_name] = [element_value,]

        try:
            if tag in doc.xpath('//Body')
                # Do stuff
                # Remove sub-elements value
                # Then save as a new file
        except:
            print('It did not work')
```